# VS2010 debugger always breaks

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010, I set a break point (from the left gutter of the editor) on a line of code. After I removed the break point, the debugger always breaks on that line of code. After starting visual studio, the debugger still breaks at the point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you removing the breakpoint while the program is running? I find that VS 2008 (and 2010) only *disables* the breakpoint then, but re-enable it on the next program invocation. If so, try removing it while the program is not running. Otherwise I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

use control+shift+f9 or goto your Debug menu and delete all breakpoints. It might be some weird bug..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a debugbreak statement in there or an asm int 3 call?